# Performance checking of Image Steganography Technique

Tags: steganography

I am working with image Steganography LSB technique (Lossless Compression) as the performance of it is measured in PSNR value. Higher PSNR value greater the performance. But what is the standered input data size? I have read some paper they mention their performance but didn't mention the data size. Any suggestion.
The size of the image I am working with is 512 x 512 and the extension is .png. In each pixel of RGB color I am hiding 4 bit of Data.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard. Why not contact the authors directly?

Comment: I think many people here are not too familiar with steganography, and from a quick google search I found PSNR only in the context of lossy compression. Maybe add some more information?

Comment: Did they use some standard image (like [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)), perhaps? Please link/point to the paper in question.

Comment: Yes, they use image like Lenna @otus

Answer (score 1):

I took a Master's level course in stego, but it was a year ago.

That said, I can base my answer on that course and this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) article.

First, the definition of PSNR is a "peak signal-to-noise ratio."  The signal is the original image, and the noise in this case is the "error introduced by compression."  The values cited in the wiki, based on the sources ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=evGyv-mogukC&lpg=PA155&dq=image%20compression%20acceptable%20PSNR&pg=PA156&hl=en#v=onepage&q=image%20compression%20acceptable%20PSNR&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FmqPOsEYRsEC&lpg=PA229&dq=image%20compression%20acceptable%20PSNR&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q=PSNR&f=false)) recommend 60 and 80 dB.  This is with respect to a [bit-depth](https://www.library.cornell.edu/preservation/tutorial/intro/intro-04.html) of 16.

The actual value you would need depends on several factors, including color scales used (monochromatic v. RBG images), and lossless v. lossy images.  Lossy images are those with irreversible data compression.  These are typical multimedia file types, e.g. audio, video, and certain images.  This is in contrast to lossless images, which have reversible data compression.

The size of the image you've given is less important compared to the bit depth and file extension.

There really is no "standard image size" that I'm aware of. Since you've stated the image is 512x512, with a bit depth of 8 and if the image is lossy then you would want values of 30 and 50 dB.  Lossy files have the extensions: JPEG, GIF.  Lossless files have extensions: RAW, BMP, PNG.  Whether the image is lossy or lossless, and the bit-depth, will change the needed PSNR.  Based on this, you should be able to determine if your PSNR is acceptable.

EDIT:

For a bit-depth of 4, or 4 bpp in a lossless PNG where the stego'd image is approximately 127 kilobytes, the equation from the wikipedia article can be used if you want to plug in the values by hand, or you can try using [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/psnr.html).

Otherwise, just by using the PSNR value you've given which is approximately 46, and based on the suggested range from the wikipedia article, they recommend values in the range of 60 and 80 dB.

If you'd really like to understand how effective your stego is, you can analyze the hexadecimal values using a tool like HexEditor Neo, and run hard forensics using a tool like StegoSec (I was trained with both, if you end up having questions about using them).  With the Least Significant Bit, you can run a cross analysis of where the hexadecimal is being manipulated (usually the red tones are favored in palettes for the LSB, if I remember correctly).

Otherwise, if you need to increase how well your stego works, you could try changing the pallette of the image you're hiding using image editors like Paint dot net and just switching the hues.  I've never tried that, but it might help shift the PSNR value in your favor.

Comment: I describe my question fro more clarify. As you mention that you worked with it, then what was the data size. I am trying to hide 131,072 byte data and the PSNR value is about 48.215. I will be glad you give me suggestion - is that PSNR value is good.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to reflect the changes in your question.

Comment: My approximation for your file size (kilobytes) and PSNR value is a bit off in my answer, but you would still need a higher value.